# Chaining jQuery promises/deferreds

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred, promise

I have a process where I have to send an ajax request to the server, but need to stop a scheduler  before the ajax request begins, then restart the scheduler when the request is done.

I have got this working using the following code:

```
scheduler.stop()
         .done(function () {
                 setQuestionStatus().done(scheduler.start);
               });
```

But it seems that there should be a simpler way to write this, such as:

```
scheduler.stop().then(setQuestionStatus).then(scheduler.start);
```

My problem is that when written this way, setQuestionStatus and scheduler.start are both called *as soon as scheduler.stop has resolved*, rather than after each item in the chain has resolved.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong in the second example?

---

For your information, both scheduler.stop and setQuestionStatus return a promise using the pattern:

```
var setQuestionStatus = function(){
  return $.Deferred(function (def) {
    // Do stuff
    def.resolve();
  }).promise();
}
```

Comment: Is your `// Do stuff` asynchronous? Because if not, the `Promise` returned by `setQuestionStatus` is *already* fulfilled before you call `then` on it.

Comment: Good point, but yes, setQuestionStatus is asynchronous, so def.resolve() only gets called in the ajax.success callback.  I should have put a little more detail into my example.

Comment: Side note: `.then(scheduler.start)` will arrange to have `start` called, but within the call, `this` will not be `scheduler`. You may want `.then($.proxy(scheduler.start, scheduler)` or `.then(scheduler.start.bind(scheduler))` (on ES5 systems).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> scheduler.stop().then(setQuestionStatus).then(scheduler.start);
> ```
>
> My problem is that when written this way, setQuestionStatus and scheduler.start are both called as soon as scheduler.stop has resolved, rather than after each item in the chain has resolved.

That's ugly non-[standard](http://promisesaplus.com/) behavior found in earlier versions of jQuery. Either update your copy to 1.8+ for using [`then`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/), or use the [`pipe` method](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.pipe/) instead.

Comment: Genius!  Updated jQuery and now works as expected.  Many thanks.